# Login function runs different between local and server

Tags: c#

Here is my check login function:

```
 protected bool checkLoginStatus(String email, String password)
    {
        bool loginStatus = false;
        bool status = false;
        try
        {
            Connector.openConn();
            String str = "SELECT * FROM [User]";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, Connector.conn);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "tblUser");

            //check valid
            foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                if (email == dr["Email"].ToString()
                    && password == Connector.base64Decode(dr["Password"].ToString()))
                {
                    Session["login_status"] = true;
                    Session["username"] = dr["Name"].ToString();
                    Session["userId"] = dr["UserId"].ToString();                   
                    status = true;
                    break;

                }

            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { }
        finally {
            Connector.closeConn();
        }
        return status;
    }
```

And call it at my aspx page:

```
        String email = Login1.UserName.Trim();
        String password = Login1.Password.Trim();

        if (checkLoginStatus(email, password))
            Response.Redirect(homeSite);
        else
            lblFailure.Text = "Invalid!";
```

I ran this page at localhost successful!
When I published it to server, this function only can run if email and password correct! Other, error occured:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

I tried open SQL Server 2008 Configuration Manager and enable SQL Server Browser service (Logon as:NT Authority/Local Service) but it stills error.

(**note**: here is connection string of openConn() **at Localhost** (run on SQLEXpress 2005)

```
connectionString="Data Source=MYLAPTOP\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Spider_Vcms;Integrated Security=True" />
```

)
At server (run on SQL Server Enterprise 2008)

```
connectionString="Data Source=SVR;Initial Catalog=Spider_Vcms;User Id=abc;password=123456;" />
```

anyone have an answer for my problem :(
thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you enabled SQL Server Authentication?

Comment: Have you enabled remote connections?

Comment: Yes. I enabled SQL Server Authentication and Remote connections. But it's not success.

I can't understand why this error occured. Because when I enter username and password correctly, I can login without any problem.
Only when I enter incorrect, this error is fired :(

Answer (score 0):

That's a pretty strage behaviour.

First of all, on what line is exception thrown? When calling `Fill()`?

Also. Was identity impersonation used previously and is still on *(although I can't see direct relation here, but whatever...)*?

Answer (score -1):

This mybe caused by the fact that SQL Server 2005 Express Edition does not allow remote connections by default:

From http://support.microsoft.com/kb/914277

> 1. Click Start, point to Programs,
>      point to Microsoft SQL Server 2005,
>      point to Configuration Tools, and
>      then click SQL Server Surface Area
>      Configuration.
> 2. On the SQL Server 2005 Surface Area
>      Configuration page, click Surface
>      Area Configuration for Services and
>      Connections.
> 3. On the Surface Area Configuration
>      for Services and Connections page,
>      expand Database Engine, click Remote
>      Connections, click Local and remote
>      connections, click the appropriate
>      protocol to enable for your
>      environment, and then click Apply.
>
>    Note: Click OK when you receive the following message:
>
>    Changes to Connection Settings will
>      not take effect until you restart the
>      Database Engine service.
> 4. On the Surface Area Configuration
>      for Services and Connections page,
>      expand Database Engine, click
>      Service, click Stop, wait until the
>      MSSQLSERVER service stops, and then
>      click Start to restart the
>      MSSQLSERVER service.

Comment: I dont think this is his problem.  He says its not working on the server which is accessing sql 2008 enterprise.